# trouble with CharAt

Tags: java, string, charat

I am suppose to make a simple program that would take a users input, and put spaces between each single letter. So for example, user enters mall, and it returns M A L L(on same line).
I am trying to make a loop with a if statement in it.But I think I would need CharAt for it, so if the string is greater value then 1, I would declare a variable to everysingle character in the string(that the userinput). Then I would say put spaces between each letter. I am in AP computer science A, and we are practicing loops.Everything underthis, is what I have done so far. And the directions are in the comment above code.And im useing eclipse,java.

```
/**
 * Splits the string str into individual characters: Small becomes S m a l l
 */
public static String split(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; str.length() > i; i++) {
        if (str.length() > 0) {
            char space = str.charAt();
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)?

Comment: What do you think `str.charAt()` without any argument should do?

Comment: Gives me an error, I am supposed to put an argument but I am so confused and lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't modify method parameters, you make copies of them.
2. You don't null-check/empty-check inside the loop, you do it first thing in the method.
3. The standard in a `for loop` is `i < size`, not `size > i`... meh

   ```
   /**
    * Splits the string str into individual characters: Small becomes S m a l l
    */
   public static String split(final String str) 
   {
       String result = "";

       // If parameter is null or empty, return an empty string
       if (str == null || str.isEmpty())
           return result;

       // Go through the parameter's characters, and modify the result
       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
       {
           // The new result will be the previous result,
           // plus the current character at position i,
           // plus a white space.
           result = result + str.charAt(i) + " ";  
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```

---

4. Go pro, use `StringBuilder` for the result, and static final constants for empty string and space character.

Peace!

Comment: 0_0 This is like information getting handed downs from masters of java to newbies.Thanks, but can you explain to me, the for loop. So first we declare int i as 0. Then we say if i is less then str.length(), increment i. So this loop stops when i is greater then str.length right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it works. Suppose you have the string `small`. That means `i` will become `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` (because `small` has 5 characters). So in each iteration, your code will look like `result=result+str.charAt(0)+" ";`, then `result=result+str.charAt(1)+" ";`, etc.

Comment: The code `str.charAt(i)` method does nothing but tell you what character is found at the position `i` in the string `str`. That's it. BE CAREFUL, the number of characters in the string starts at 0!!!

Comment: Go pro, use regex: `String result = "small".replaceAll("\\B", " ")` or simpler without regex `"small".replace("", " ").trim()` :)

Comment: @Pshemo That's beyond pro. Well, I guess we all learn something everyday. The point is, dude wanted to know about `charAt(int)`.

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses `concat` to build the `str2`, and `trim` to remove last white space.

```
public static String split(String str) {
     String str2 = "";
     for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        str2 = str2.concat(str.charAt(i)+" ");
     }
     return str2.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself a question, where is **s** coming from?

```
char space = s.charAt(); ??? s ???
```

A second question, character at?

```
public static String split(String str){
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.length() > 0) {
            char space = str.charAt(i)
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: In eclipse it wont let me have your first line char space = str.charAt();, it says I should put something in the parameter

Comment: The first line was to illustrate the error you make. You tried to call s which does not exist. Second you dont use an index in the charAt method. Just remove 'char space = s.charAt(); ??? s ???'

Answer (score 0):

@Babanfaraj, this a answer from a newbie like you!!
The code is very easy. The corrected program is-

```
class fopl
{
    public static void main(String str) 
    {
    int n=str.length();
        for (int i = 0;i<n; i++) 
    {
        if (n>=0) 
        {
            String space = str.charAt(i)+" ";
            System.out.print(space);
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Happy to help you!